# primitive roots and primes

Tags: prime-numbers, nt.number-theory, primitive-roots

Given a positive integer $n > 1$, is it true that there exists infinitely many primes $p$ such that $n$ is a primitive root modulo $p$.

Comment: What is the motivation of your question?

Comment: It's a natural question, isn't it? But I think this is wide open. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin's_conjecture_on_primitive_roots .

Comment: Well, it would be still nice to have some discussion of the problem and not just throw up a (probably unsolved) question. 

Comment: Artin's conjecture assumes that $n$ is not a square. Otherwise it's false.

Answer (score 21):

There is a simple answer here, so someone might as well record it.

Let $n$ be a nonzero integer.  If $n = -1$ or $n$ is a square then there is no prime $p > 3$ such that $n$ is a primitive root modulo $p$.  There are no other obvious obstructions.  (It is worth thinking for a second why we do not have to rule out $n$ being a cube, for instance: this is a nice exercise in cyclic group theory.)

There is a famous conjecture that these obvious necessary conditions are the only ones: namely [Artin's Primitive Root Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots) asserts that for any integer $n$ which is not $0$, $-1$ and not a square, there are infinitely many prime numbers $p$ such that $n$ is a primitive root modulo $p$.  In fact the conjecture is more precise than this: the set of primes $p$ for which such an $n$ is a primitive root is conjectured to have positive relative density among all primes and, at least under some mild additional restrictions, this density is conjectured to be a certain specific number which is independent of $n$:

$ C = \prod_{p \text{ prime}} \left(1- \frac{1}{p(p-1)} \right)$;

this $C$ is known as **Artin's constant**.  This conjecture was proved by C. Hooley in 1967 assuming the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis.  More recently unconditional results have been given by Gupta, R. Murty and Heath-Brown which consider several numbers $n$ at a time and show that Artin's Conjecture must be true for at least one of them.  But the conjecture is still open for any one fixed value of $n$.

Comment: Um, you folks do realize that I'm mostly repeating material from the wikipedia article I linked to (and Qiaochu pointed out first), right?  Just so you know...

Comment: technically -1 is a primitive root modulo p=3.
I still like your answer though.

Comment: @Greg: good point.  I have changed my answer accordingly.  

Answer (score 12):

It showed up in a [recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62787) so one might wonder. The article [Artin's conjecture for primitive roots](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~murty/mi.dvi), Math. Intelligencer, 10 (4) (1988) 59-67 by Ram Murty seems like a good survey. The link is to a dvi copy. It informs one that the result follows from a Generalized Riemann Hypothesis and is unconditionally true for at least one of $2,3,5.$

The first $12000$ primes for which $7$ is a primitive root run from $11$ to $378011$. This proportion $\frac{12000}{32141} \approx 0.3734$ agrees well with the theoretical expected proportion of $\prod(1-\frac{1}{p(p-1)}) \approx 0.3739$ where the product is over the primes. The distribution according to congruence class $\mod 7$ is $[1, 1748], [2, 2074], [3, 2032], [4, 2058], [5, 2065], [6, 2023].$ This slight deficit in congruence class 1 seems to hold through this range.